# Use Calendar.SelectedDate in Postback Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I'm using some nested `Repeater`s.
The data of the inner repeaters are set in the `Repeater.OnItemCreated` event.

This data is relative to the `SelectedDate` of the `Calendar`.

Unfortunately, the `SelectedDate` is not set until somewhere before the `Page_Load` method is called, so I get an empty `DateTime` in my `Repeater.OnItemCreated` method.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Why do you use `OnItemCreated` instead of `OnItemDataBound`? Have you disabled `ViewState`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Let's say I'm a ASP newbie :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well now I feel really stupid, moving the code from `OnItemCreated` to `OnItemDataBound` solved the problem. You can add this as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `OnItemCreated` instead of `OnItemDataBound`? Have you disabled `ViewState`?

In general `OnItemDataBound` is the event that should be used for databinding. `OnItemCreated` must be used if you need to create controls dynamically since this event is triggered on every postback and not only if the repeater gets databound.